# How do I hide the output from a subprocess and continue the script execution?

Tags: python, subprocess

How do I start a subprocess or run a python file that has a continuous stream of output and simultaneously run the rest of the script?

here is some example code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('python myScript.py', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

#this program will have a stream of output and is designed to run for
#long periods of time

print 'the program is still running!'

doMoreStuff()
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this script? It looks like it does what you are asking.

Comment: The problem, is that the script has outputs that I cannot control. A better example would have been a command that executes a sniffer or somthing with a constant stream of output. For whatever reason, the program is spewing out information that I dont need. I need to know how to run that command and disregard the output while returning to the rest of the script and not outputting random garbage.

Comment: You aren't seeing `stdout` data so the stuff you see is `stderr`. Generally, what do you want to happen to the data? Dump it? Write it to a file? Keep it in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling subprocess.Popen() in your sample code, the main process will immediately comes to the print() statement and then execute doMoreStuff(), running the rest of script simultaneously.

Comment: My sample code is an example, what I'm trying to do is execute a program that is outputting data in a way that disrupts my program.

Comment: So you want to ignore the outputs from myScript.py? By changing `subprocess.Popen('python myScript.py', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` into `subprocess.Popen('python myScript.py >  /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` in **Linux** or `subprocess.Popen('python myScript.py >  NUL', shell=True)` in **Windows**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program to be silent, you need to capture `stderr` as well as `stdout`. Two choices are `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` meaning you want to interleave stdout and err on the stdout pipe. Or `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to keep stderr distinct.

But you have a second problem. Because you don't read `stdout`, if the program outputs enough data to fill the pipe it will hang. There is a potential third problem - somewhere along the line you need to call `p.wait()` so that you don't end up with zombie processes.

You could send them to a file:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('python myScript.py', shell=True, 
    stdout=open('stdout.txt', 'wb'), stderr=open('stderr.txt', 'wb'))
```

Or have background threads do the work:

```
def out_err_thread(out_err_list, proc):
    out, err = proc.communicate()

proc = subprocess.Popen('python myScript.py', shell=True, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out_err = []
_t = threading.Thread(target=out_err_thread, args=(out_err, proc))
_t.start()
```

Or send them to the bit bucket

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('python myScript.py', shell=True, 
    stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```